# File Upload not posting / MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload a file from my view to my controller, but the value is always null.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(AttachmentDto dto, HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile)
```

Form Tag:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Edit")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Input Tag:

```
<input type="file" name="UploadedFile" id="File"  />
```

There are few other inputs being passed into the controller that the dto is receiving, however the UploadedFile is always null? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your code as shown is working for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dtj1.png. Are you using AJAX or something to POST the form?

Comment: Nope, just using a button. 
<button type="submit" name="save"><span></span>Save</button>

Comment: So using a button with type="submit" seems to cause some issue. When I switch to using just an <input> as submit it works fine..

Comment: mmm, sensing something maybe with the view - can you post the full code? 
Also maybe, you need [HttpPost] on top of that Edit action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mystery turned out to be a JavaScript import that was added to the project by a colleague to handle our form posts. There is already a question regarding posting multipart/formdata using jQuery here:
[Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Just added the FormData object and presto.

Thanks for all of your help!